# Ruby on Rails form helper

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to Rails and have been having some trouble trying to find tutorials that actually work for me. I am attempting to create a database in MySQL and then allow users to submit information to this database through a form. I was able to create a form using the code below but it only triggers the new method in the Controller and not the create method. Does anyone know why this is happening and/or can guide me to a good tutorial for building forms. I have found some in google but for some reason the syntax never works for me when I try to enter it. Thank you very much in advance for any help you can give.

Controller -

```
class MessageController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new
    @message.message=params[:mess]
    @message.user=params[:name]
    if @message.save
        redirect_to "http://itworks.com"
        end
  end
end
```

View -

```
<%= form_for :MessageController do |f| -%>
        Message: <%= f.text_field :mess %><br />
        UserName: <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
        <%= f.submit%>
    <% end -%>
```

Edit - When I change :MessageController to @message or :message I get a syntax error. (syntax error, unexpected keyword ensure, expecting $end. Surprisingly enough the form works with :MessageController but it only triggers the new method not the create method.

Comment: In Rails, you will never need to use a CamelCase symbol. You'll never see something like `:MessageController` in idiomatic Ruby code. Even if that were the correct way of using `form_for`, you would use `:message_controller`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`form_for` expects either an instance of a model, or a symbol representing the name of a variable containing an instance of a model. You've given it the name of a controller.

Use this:

```
<%= form_for :message do |f| -%>
```

or thiS:

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| -%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're new, let me explain some things for you:

--

[**form_for**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| -%>
    <%= f.label :mess %>
    <%= f.text_field :mess %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When you use `form_for`, you basically need to populate it with an ActiveRecord object. Currently, you're using the `MessageController` class, which is totally wrong. You've already set the `@message` object in your controller - you just need to populate your `form_for` method with it

--

**Strong Params**

Secondly, as I already mentioned in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463285/rails-undefined-method/24464886#24464886), you need to ensure you're using the `strong params` functionality of Rails correctly:

```
#app/controllers/message_controller.rb
Class MessageController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @message = Message.new(message_params)
        @message.save
    end

    private

    def message_params
        params.require(:message).permit(:mess, :user)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still pretty new to Rails as well, but it looks like your syntax for the form_for method is off a bit. Here's the example from the rails guide for form helpers:

```
<%= form_for @article, url: {action: "create"}, html: {class: "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12" %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

And here's the link to the form helper page: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

I've found the rubyonrails.org guides to be the best resource for trouble-shooting. The documentation is actually quite good(both extensive and clear).

Answer (score -1):

I guess that maybe caused by the "Strong parameter",
to learn more you can see [Strong Parameters by Example](http://blog.sensible.io/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html) here.

In the Messages controller, we could add the strong parameter to it

```
class MessageController < ApplicationController
 def new
   @message = Message.new
 end

 def create
   @message = Message.new(message_params)
   @message.message=params[:mess]
   @message.user=params[:name]
   if @message.save
       redirect_to "http://itworks.com"
   end
 end
 private
 def message_params
   params.require(:message).permit(:mess, :name)
 end
end
```

Because you define the `@message` , so..why not use it?

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
    Message: <%= f.text_field :mess %><br />
    UserName: <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
    <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```